# How to track organic vs paid-ad facebook users in my app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, ads

I am using facebook sdk in my app for tracking of ads and install counts. Is there any way to know whether the source of new app install is facebook ad or not.

I read facebook sdk documentation but couldn't find a direct way to do it.

Comment: I was also facing this problem. Let me know if you if you find anything

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible at the moment.

Comment: @sider I think it's should a common problem that is faced by any organizations? How do they solve it. Is there any hack or something

Comment: @sider is there any hack or something? which can i use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook's mobile app install ads support [deep linking](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking). You can use that to send install attribution data into the app. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30236116/1296709) explains how.

Answer (score 0):

I helped build and actively maintain a free deep linking platform called [branch.io](https://branch.io) that can do this very easily for both Android or iOS. The tool leverages a public API that Facebook has to check if a new device came from a Facebook ad, app invite or whatever. You can read more about this [public API here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/activities/).

Let me explain how to set up and use it.

1. Head to dashboard.branch.io and create a Branch link. Add in labels for `campaign`, `channel`, etc depending on your use case. If you want to stuff custom parameters in, you can add unlimited keys/values in the `deep link data` section at the bottom.

   Here's what it would look like: https://bnc.lt/m/3vk4ENnQcm
2. Once you have your Branch link, you're ready to make an advertisement. While creating your advertisement, you simply need to paste the link into the 'Deep Link' field as in the screenshot below.

[image]

3. Lastly, you want to know client side (after install) if the user came from an advertisement or not. To do this, you simply make a call to the Branch library in your App Delegate for iOS or splash Activity in Android. The callback block in the below example will contain all of the parameters of the link you created on the dashboard.

   ```
    Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
    [branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions 
              andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"finished init with deep link params = %@", [params description]);
        }
    }];
   ```

I hope this helps!

Comment: What language is that? it doesn't seem like standard java. Do you have a java version?